# Ruby on Rails - Need to use an older version of ruby for an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My issue is trying to create a local server so I can understand an app that's been developed by my new team. My issue is that I'm using Ruby 2.3.3, and the Gemfile requires 2.3.1. I'm not able to edit the Gemfile as I've been told it would be difficult to change the Ruby versions. The relevant code from the command line:

```
C:\Sites>cd app

C:\Sites\app>rails server
Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1
```

Because of this, how can I downgrade my Ruby to 2.3.1, so I can create the local server and start progressing with this app? I've looked at rvm, and, to be quite honest, it's confusing in regards to installation and usage, so I haven't had success.

I'm using Windows 10, if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the Ruby version in the Gemfile to 2.3.3? It's just two minor revisions diff so it may still work fine.

Comment: Install `rvm` then `rvm install 2.3.1`. Mostly no need, just for secure purpose `rvm use 2.3.1`.

Comment: I would consider using docker or some other sort of virtualization so that your teams: A) have the same setup to avoid "it works for me" issues.  B) Are developing in an environment  as close as possible to the one you are deploying too (this includes the same OS)

Comment: Trying to use it on a different OS than the rest of the team is fraught with peril.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would leverage a Ruby version management tool such as [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to install multiple versions of Ruby. To accomplish this on Windows you would need to use a different terminal/shell such as GitBash or Ubuntu Bash on Windows. I highly recommend doing this anyways when doing development on Windows.